# Android Calendar View with Events and Daily View Library

Tags: android, kotlin, events, calendarview

I am trying to find a library similar to [this](https://github.com/AnilMH/Android-WeekView-Demo.git). I need daily view calendar with events. I cannot find anything similar enough to this and useful.

[image: And]

Comment: Are you got the solution?

Comment: No, I have not found any solution

Comment: Please check this lib :- 

https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View